# Retrieve c# Dictionary value type

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary of string(key) and Object(value). How can I get Type of each Value in Dictionary?

Sample code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> jsonData;
ArrayList arr =  new ArrayList();

arr.Add("1");
arr.Add("2");    
arr.Add("3");

jsonData["status"] = "200";
jsonData["data"] = arr;


foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in jsonData)
{
     item.Value    
     //  type string vs ArrayList ??
}
```

Comment: `Object.GetType()` gets the Type of the current instance. you can then compare it like this: `item.Value.GetType() == typeof( classnamehere )`  or `if(item.Value is classnamehere)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  try-cast the value to these types with the [`as`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in jsonData)
{
    ArrayList list;
    string str;
    if ((list = item.Value as ArrayList) != null)
    { 

    }
    else if ((str = item.Value as string) != null)
    { 

    }
}
```

Another way is to use the [`is`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in jsonData)
{
    if (item.Value is ArrayList)
    { 
        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) item.Value;
    }
    else if (item.Value is string)
    { 
        string str = (string) item.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @tickles: that is never  `true`. You have to use `if (item.Value is ArrayList)`. That's another way. I have used one that tries to cast so that you can use the object immediately afterwards.

Comment: If you are comparing with `is` you dont have to call `GetType()`

Comment: @tickles: i have shown you the alternative in my answer.

Comment: thanks ~~~ I'm not good at English.